# How can I use Entity Framework from ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting started with ASP.NET and I have a problem. I created an MVC4 application in the Visual Studio. Then to the Models I added an ADO.NET Entity Data Model with the Database first method. Everything okay until I try to add a new Controller when I get an error message: `'Projectname.Models.Tablename' is not part of specified 'Projectname.Models.Contextname' class and the 'Projectname.Models.Contextname' class could not be modified to add a DbSet<Projectname.Models.Tablename> property to it.`
What is my mistake?

Here is my generated model:

```
  public partial class Example
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

End here is my generated context:

```
public partial class TestEntities : DbContext
    {
        public TestEntities()
            : base("name=TestEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<Example> Example { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: If you posted some code showing what you've done you'd greatly help people trying to help you.

Comment: Try adding the ADO.NET entity data model to the root of the application rather than in a folder.

Comment: I tried it in the root folder too, but it did not helped.

Comment: I put the understandable part of the code to the question.